# Safari cannot detect WebView pages on APP

Tags: webview, safari

I can WebView APP online debugging in Safari, but not after the commissioning package, Safari WebView could not be detected ", showed no application can check, after the packing is placed on fir.im, WebView using UIWebView, using webviewbridge

The WebView checker on my cell phone has been turned on. It can be debugged on line, but it cannot be packed

I've been looking for a lot of answers, but I can't find anyone. Thank you

Comment: I use swift3.0 , xcode9,phone is ios10

Answer (score 0):

I use UIWebViewJavascriptBridge
    func createUI() {
        lmrWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 64, width: lmr_width, height: lmr_height - 64))

```
    lmrWebView.backgroundColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackground
    lmrWebView.delegate = self
    lmrWebView.scalesPageToFit = true

    guard let url:URL = URL(string: webUrl) else { return }

    let urlReq: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    lmrWebView.loadRequest(urlReq)

    self.view.addSubview(lmrWebView)
    self.view.addSubview(self.myProgressView)
}
```